# Array is showing up as empty, yet it contains values

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

[image]
Can anyone help me understand why the Array is showing as being empty, when it also shows that it has data/ values ?

I am not able to access the data. See picture for reference.

Comment: @Teemu He will find the reason. How others will find it? You explain it here.

Comment: You can tell us, what the tooltip of that info mark says exactly. I don't have Chrome at hands right now, but the idea is, that the line with info mark is populated at different time than the property list. The basic reason is, that `console.log` is asynchronous. Why you can't access data is hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: A speculative guess would be, that you're logging a value from asynchronously populated data too early. If that's the case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Objects logged in the Javascript console are "live", so expanding them shows the current contents of the object. The first line shows that the `outputList` was empty when you first called `console.log()`. But something was added to the array later, and when you expanded the object by clicking on the disclosure triangle, you see the updated value.

Comment: Terrible nomenclature...

Comment: To see real data you can use console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.outputList))); This would copy object so you would see expected data.

Comment: @VugarAbdullayev I usually suggest just `console.log(JSON.stringify(...))`, although your method makes the object inspectable.