# JavaScript array have length of 1 but its empty?

Tags: javascript

I am facing this unexpected behavior using `array.push` as you can see the array districts have a length of 1 but when you open it its empty.

code:

```
  districts_modules.forEach((item) => {
    item.modules_id.forEach((insight) => {
      userRoles[modules[parseInt(insight) - 1]].buildings.push({
        districtName: item.districtName,
        districtId: item.district_id,
        buildings: [],
      });

      userRoles[modules[parseInt(insight) - 1]].districts.push({
        label: item.districtName,
        value: item.district_id,
      });
      console.log(userRoles[modules[parseInt(insight) - 1]]);
    });
  });
```

[image]

i don't know why this happening. any explanation.

Comment: how are you pushing value there? Seems there are some other operation performed after pushing the value

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637106/array-is-showing-up-as-empty-yet-it-contains-values

Comment: @brk  added the code .