# Passing data into Angular 13 modal

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, race-condition

I'm trying to **pass data into a modal**. The modal is a separate component alltogether.

I'm able to console.log the bsModalRef property in the constructor, but for some reason, I can't console.log the bsModalRef.content property.

Here is my code in the page I'm launching the modal from...

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
        type="button"
        (click)="openDeleteModal(result.id)">
Edit
</button>
```

Here is the code for that openDeleteModal() method...

```
public openDeleteModal(id: number): void {

  this.selectedCase = this.listOfSearchResults.filter(result => result.id == id);

  const initialState: ModalOptions = {
    initialState: {
      list: [
        this.selectedCase
      ],
      title: 'Edit Case',
      whatYouWantToDelete: 'this error'
    }
  };
  this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(DeleteModalComponent, initialState);
}
```

Now, for the code in the modal itself, I'm importing BsModalRef like this...

```
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
```

Here are the properties I set...

```
title?: string;
whatYouWantToDelete?: string;
list?: any[];
initialState: any;
```

and this is what I have for the constructor...

```
constructor(
    public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private http: HttpClient) {
    this.list = this.list;
    console.log("this.list: ", this.list);
    console.log("this.bsModalRef in constructor: ", this.bsModalRef);
    console.log("this.bsModalRef.content in constructor: ", this.bsModalRef.content);
  }
```

this is the screenshot of what I'm seeing in the console.log...

[image]

And this is the content part of the BsModalRef object...

[image]

My question is, **how do I access that data** in the list property from the constructor? That object has properties that I need to populate a form I have in the modal.

Stated differently...

this line of code...

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(DeleteModalComponent, initialState);
```

opens the modal and passes in the data as initialState. How do I access the data that I'm passing in through the initialState object from within **the modal itself**?

Here is a screenshot that shows I can see the data in the NgOnInit, but the issue is I can't get that data to show up in the modal html file.
[image]

Here is the **html in the delete component** file where I'm trying to display the list.

```
<p>Are you sure you want to delete {{ this.whatYouWantToDelete }}?</p>

<p>id selected: {{ this.products }}</p>

<div *ngFor="let user of this.list; index as i">
   Case Id: {{user.caseId}}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think list would have the scope of `this`. Try `console.log(this.bsModalRef.content.list)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 key notes here:

1. Objects logged in the Javascript console are "live", so expanding them shows the current contents of the object. Content.list was empty when you first called console.log(). Then data was updated and hence on console too.  See [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637106/array-is-showing-up-as-empty-yet-it-contains-values)

In order to see real data I prefer this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.bsModalRef)));
```

2. Seems there is issue with bsModalRef. You can access content via:

`setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.bsModalRef.content), 0});`

But it is a workaound. You should report this to ngx-bootstrap [repository](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap).

Comment: Thanks, I used this and it works, but by the time the setTimeout function is completed, the form has already been created on the html page and it doesn't populate with the data. So it's a race condition. How do I tell the html page to populate as soon as the data is ready?

Comment: <form *ngIf="content?.list"> </form>

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I access that data in the list property from the constructor? That object has properties that I need to populate a form I have in the modal.

The proper way to access data is within [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit#ngoninit) lifecycle hook method .

`title`, `whatYouWantToDelete` and `list` data would be present within ngOnInit; you don't need to access it via bsModalRef instance.
Try this:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.list);
  console.log(this.whatYouWantToDelete);
  console.log(this.title);
}
```

**Edit:**

Since `this.list` is an array of array as per the screenshot, it means that `user` is an array within ngFor. Try `user[0]?.caseId`

Comment: Thanks, however, my problem is NOT that I can't access the data in the ngOnInit().

I can.

It's just that I can't get it to display in the modal.

I've edited my original post to include a new screenshot. It shows that console.log does successfully "see" the list data. But I can't get it to display in the html for the modal.

Comment: If these values are accessible within `DeleteModalComponent` ngOnInit, then they should be available within html template too. Can you please share minimal reproduction of the issue via Stackblitz?

Comment: @CodeJunkie Can you share the html template code, it seems you are directly using `this.list` or some another object within html

Comment: I just updated my original post to show the code from the delete component html file. I'm using a ngFor to loop through this.list, which is an array of one object. I'm trying to then access user.caseId, but the problem is, since it's undefined in the constructor, it "reads it too soon". In other words, by the time, this.list is populated, the html is ALREADY set on the page. So it's a race condition.

Comment: @CodeJunkie data is available in html, it's just not being referred correctly. `this.list` is an array of array as per the screenshot. So that means in `ngFor`, `user` is an array . Try `user[0]?.caseId`

Comment: WOW! That worked. Thank you so much man! I didn't see that it was an array of arrays.